# QLabel image rotate on another image

Tags: c++, qt5, qlabel

I try to make clock on QLabel and control needle rotate

And I  put needle.png on clock.png.

I want to control angle let QLabel work like needle rotate on clock.

I don't know how to rotate needle.png.

How to achieve this rotate needle.png on clock.png.

Comment: you can use a QTransformation and rotate the image

Answer (score 1):

use a transformation

```
QPixmap orig (":/n/apple-touch-icon.png");
QTransform t;
t.rotate(45+i);
ui->label->setPixmap(orig.transformed(t).scaledToWidth(32));
i+=10;
```